# How to debug whether automapper mappings are correct or not when used with entity framework

Tags: automapper

When using AutoMapper in conjunction with Entity Framework more often I have faced issues with mapping.

Is there a way to check if the maps created using `CreateMap` are correct or not?

I don't see any errors but I get the object as `null` in my post method.

Any thoughts on how to debug AutoMapper issues especially when no errors come up in build/output window and enabling `AssetConfigurationIsValid()`

Comment: If you call AssetConfigurationIsValid() after initializing your Auto Mapper you'll get exception when mappigns are incorrect. How do you initialize your mapper and mappings?

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Basically I created a new mapperconfiguration and to have createMap statements under it to specify the mappings and then I do an AssertConfigurationIsValid before calling CreateMapper. I dont see any errors however I am suspecting that there could be issues with the way entityframework is formulating the queries due to the mapping.

Comment: How does one interpret the execution plan. I am not sure what to look into while reviewing the plan

Comment: Well, at this point it's just code. With Map it's imperative code similar to what you would write by hand and with ProjectTo it's the select statement that will be passed to EF.

Comment: Well, `AssetConfigurationIsValid` is the way to check whether maps created are valid or not. If you have a problem, post that code instead.

Comment: I have checked the mappings and looks like the automapper mappings seems to be ok as I am able to write unit tests to pass an entity to dto and vice versa. My guess is that when it hits entity framework something else happens. I am still to figure out how to check whats happening in EF